# ServiceStack - Request Classes with Same Name in Different Namespaces Throws Error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, domain-driven-design, servicestack, servicestack-text

My project contains a large set of services which we've grouped into different domains which allows us to call them using corressponding Urls i.e.

Domain 1

```
/FlightManagementDomain/SeatMaps
/FlightManagementDomain/Passengers
```

Domain 2

```
/ReservationsDomain/Tickets
/ReservationsDomain/Bookings
```

I could let teams of developers work on each namespace. No errors get thrown even if two teams create two classes with the same name in each namespace for request/response/controller objects.

Since I wanted to switch over to service stack I wrote a POC using SS with the following structure

[image: Solution Structure]

Note that I'm using the same name for the request object "GetUsersRequest". This compiles and runs fine but when I click the json or xml links in the metadata page, it throws the following error "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

[image: Error]

The Service Host configuration looks like this

[image: Configuration]

Now if I change one of the class names from "GetUsersRequest" to "GetUsersRequest1" it works as expected and the error goes away.

I have a doubt that SS is using Type.Name instead of Type.FullName somewhere in the code. Is there a way to avoid this error without renaming the request class?

I've attached the complete source code here [link to source code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1FTb0VQ85FHdXE3Z0xjc0xUNFE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont work because Request DTO Names must be unique in ServiceStack. C# Namespaces are internal implementation detail and do not carry any meaning over the wire.